# Boat's in the water

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the meaning of expression "Boat's in the water"? I've heard it in the TV-show "Mad men" S1E4. Is there a way of how i can logically come to understanding of expression by myself? It's a start of conversation between father and son, who haven't seen each other for some time. Son was just married not long time ago and he came to his father's house and so their conversation begins with this phrase. I guess it means something like "everything goes alright".

Comment: Please could you clarify what you're stuck on? As it stands, it means that the boat is in the water. We'll need more context, if the sentence is metaphorical.

Comment: It's a start of conversation between father and son, who haven't seen each other for some time. As i understood it's something like statement "so, everything is alright" without questioning "how is it going".

Comment: In which case, please [explain that in your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/514171/edit), and add a bit more of the quote. Good luck!

Comment: It isn't a common expression. I don't know what kind of language is used in Mad Men. I would guess it means either "We've made a start" or, since boats are often pulled out of the water to spend winter on the hard, "Winter is over".

Comment: "We've made a start" looks reasonable. Son was just married not long time ago and he came to his father's house and so their conversation begins with this phrase. I guess it means something like "everything goes alright". But without context it would be hard to understand. Also, i can't imagine where else it could be used.

Comment: And i can add some info about what kind of language is used in Mad Men. Action happens in 60's in Manhattan, New York. This is the language used mostly by rich American businessman of that time.

Comment: @Anvar F OK. Thanks. It is shown here in the UK but I've never watched it.